# Linq (EF) where clause with string comma seperated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I have C# Lambda linq query as follow:

```
public IQueryable<CtArticleDetail> GetArticleDetailsByTagNames(string tagNames)
{
    return db.CtArticleTags.Where(m => tagNames.Contains(m.CtTag.Name) 
                                       && m.CtArticleDetail.ExpirationDate > DateTime.Now
                                       && m.CtArticleDetail.ArticleStatusId == (int)ArticleStatus.Published)
                           .Select(m => m.CtArticleDetail).OrderBy(x => x.LiveDate).Distinct();
}
```

This returns slightly wrong data list because of "Contains".   The parameter actually comes this format:  EG ( "AterSale,GeneralSale").  The result list contains other sale type articles.EG ("Sale" or "ImportedSale").

The reuslt list should be exact list as parameter passed. Can anyone pls advice ?

```
var mustContain = new[] {"A", "B");

var foos = new  List<Foo>(){
     new Foo1 {Tags = "A"},
     new Foo1 {Tags = "B"},
     new Foo2 {Tags = "A"},
     new Foo2 {Tags = "C"}
};
```

I just need Foo1 if mustcontain is  A,B

Comment: can you post some dummy data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly `tagNames` is a string which is a list of tagNames separated by comma. Then you could use `String.Split`:

```
String[] tags = tagNames.Split(new[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
return db.CtArticleTags.Where(m => tags.Contains(m.CtTag.Name) && m.CtArticleDetail.ExpirationDate > DateTime.Now
            && m.CtArticleDetail.ArticleStatusId == (int)ArticleStatus.Published)
            .Select(m => m.CtArticleDetail).OrderBy(x => x.LiveDate).Distinct();
```

---

According to your comment

> What about If I need multiple condition. EG. Let say - 'tags' contains
>   sale,aftersale. I like to retrieve that article must have SALE and
>   AFTERSALE tagged. Not only SALE or AFTERSALE

You can use `Enumerable.All`, here's a Linq-To-Objects example which you can hopefully convert to Linq-To-Entities:

```
var mustContain = new[] { "A", "B" };
var foos = new List<Foo>() { 
    new Foo{Tags="A,B"},
    new Foo{Tags="B"},
    new Foo{Tags="C,A"},
    new Foo{Tags="D"},
    new Foo{Tags="B,A,C"},
    new Foo{Tags="F,C,A,D,B"},
};

var result = foos
    .Where(f => mustContain.All(mc =>  
        f.Tags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Contains(mc)));
```

Comment: What about If I need multiple condition. EG.  Let say - 'tags' contains  sale,aftersale.  I like to retrieve that article must have SALE and AFTERSALE tagged. Not only SALE or AFTERSALE

Comment: @coder: I thought `CtTag.Name` is a string and not a `List<String>`. Do you want to split this string too?

Comment: yes. CtTag.Name is string.  Sorry, let me explian clearly:        
ArticleTagTable
Article1 Sale
Article2 Sale
Article2 AfterSale  : when parameter passed sale,aftersale, the list should return article2 only.

Comment: @coder: If the `Name` property is also a comma separated list of tags and you want to ensure that each of the tag in `tagNames` is contained in that property, you can use above code. I've also added an example (Linq To Objects).

Comment: please see the below question